# SQL query for percentage of counts grouped by month

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting a message saying the expression is an invalid identifier. I also get the message saying that the single group by isn't valid. Please kindly suggest an alternate.

I have the following Oracle SQL statement:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE
            WHEN PDRVARIANCE >= -1 then '1'
            WHEN PDRVARIANCE <-1 then '0'
          END) 
         / count(*) 
         * 100 as PercentCompliance ,
       TO_CHAR (ACTUALFINISHDATE,'MM/YY') AS DCSMONTH
  FROM    ACTIVITIES
WHERE DCSMONTH IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY DCSMONTH
```

Existing Data would be something like this...

```
Variance     Month
   20       10/12
   3.2      10/12
   -4.2     10/12
   -27.8    10/12
   13       11/12
   3        11/12
   -1.2     12/12
   -2       12/12
```

Desired outcome is to do a percentage of "true" versus "false" for each variance condition and group by month and display it as...

```
Percent   Month
    50    10/12
    100   11/12
    0     12/12
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use column aliases in the same scope they were defined.

You either have to replace `GROUP BY DSCMONTH` with `GROUP BY TO_CHAR (ACTUALFINISHDATE,'MM/YY')` (and do the same thing for where-clause), or to wrap your query inside another query.

Like,

```
select dcsmonth, sum(data) / count(*) * 100 percentcompliance 
  from (
SELECT CASE WHEN PDRVARIANCE >= -1 then 1
            WHEN PDRVARIANCE <-1 then 0 END data,
       TO_CHAR (ACTUALFINISHDATE,'MM/YY') AS DCSMONTH
  FROM  ACTIVITIES 
WHERE ACTUALFINISHDATE IS NOT NULL
)
GROUP BY DCSMONTH
```

Comment: YYYAAAAAAAYYYYYYYYY!!!!!!! So, I must admit that I am not a newbie, but not a regular at SQL scripting. This was a DUH! moment. Thanks so much and have a great holiday.